# How can I modify program to set array range from 0 to 100 in program below

Tags: c

I need the code below to recognize if the grades entered is below 1 or greater than 100.  If it is not within the parameters, I want to let the user know and allow them to enter another grade without exiting the program or losing grades they have already entered. I don't want the program to quit until the user enters q and I want to ensure all of the valid grades entered print at that time.  I have tried numerous methods and am not getting the right results.  I think I probably need some other else if statement, but I haven't been able to find the right one to work.  Any information you can share to get me on the right track would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    char choice;
    int gradeArray[100];
    int grades;
    int gCount=0,i;
    for(gCount=0; gCount<100; gCount++)
    {
        //for loop to read the grades till array size
        printf("******Enter Choice Selection in Parenthesis******\n Add grades(a)\n Quit(q) \n");
        scanf("%c",&choice);
        if(choice == 'a' || 'A')
        {
            //if user choice is a, then read the grade
            printf( "Enter grade: ");
            scanf("%d", &grades);
            getchar();
            gradeArray[gCount] = grades; //add the grade to array
        }
        if(choice == 'q') //if the user choice is q, then exit the loop
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("Grades are:\n");
    for(i=0; i<gCount; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d%%\n", gradeArray[i]); //print grades
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not use scanf.  You will waste your time debugging format strings and none of that effort will provide any useful learning.  Use fgetc, fgets, and strtol.

Comment: So I am not familiar with fgetc, fgets or strtol.  So would I replace the scanf with one of these in all places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your solution is almost aligned with what you had in mind. Here is how you can do it differently.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char choice;
    int arraySize = 100;  //change this to any number you wish
    int gradeScore = 0;
    int gradeArray[arraySize];
    int gCount = 0;
    int showCount = 0;

    while(choice != 'q')
    {
        //to ask for user's input every time
        printf("What do you want to do? Enter\n");
        printf("'a' to add grades\n");
        printf("'q' to quit\n");
        scanf(" %c", &choice);  //space is entered to ensure the compiler does not read whitespaces

        //your implementation should check for user input before proceeding
        if(choice != 'a')
        {
            //in this condition, 'q' is technically an incorrect input but your design states that 'q' is for quitting
            //thus, do not alert the user here if 'q' is entered

            if(choice != 'q')
            {
                //a condition to warn the user for incorrect input
                printf("Incorrect input. Please enter only 'a' or 'q'\n");
            }
        }

        else if(choice == 'a')
        {
           printf("Enter grade: \n");
            scanf(" %d", &gradeScore);

            //to check for user input if the grades entered are less than 1 or more than 100
            if(gradeScore < 1 || gradeScore >100)
            {
               //print a warning message
                printf("The grade you entered is invalid. Please enter a grade from 1 - 100\n");
            }

            //for all correct inputs, store them in an array
            else
            {
                printf("Grade entered\n");
                gradeArray[gCount] = gradeScore;
                gCount++;
            }

        }

    }

    //prints grade when 'q' is entered
    if(choice == 'q')
    {
        printf("Grades are: \n");


        for(showCount = 0; showCount < gCount ; showCount++)
        {
          printf("%d\n", gradeArray[showCount]);
        }

    }
}
```

To sum up the important parts, be sure to check for the user grade input to be in range of 1 - 100. Store the grade in the array if it is within range and be sure to increase the array counter, otherwise it will always store it in gradeArray[0] for the subsequent grades. Hope this helps

Comment: So you reconfigured the way I was checking for the choices to the top and then dealt with the valid option and the 1 - 100 parameter.  This makes a lot of sense.  If you don't mind, why was there a need for showCount in addition to gCount.  Initially, I was using i where showCount is now showing in the for statement.  Can you elaborate that piece so I have a better understanding of the logic behind that please?

Comment: gCount can be manipulated anywhere in the int main(), you want to make sure it is only used for 1 purpose only, which is to keep track of the array elements stored. It may work well to only use gCount all the way, but it may not be the case for future proofing.

So lets say now showCount is gCount in the last for loop and user enters 5 sets of grades. For some reason now, you wish to show the user only 0, 1 , 2 sets of grade to the user. After the loop ends, gCount = 2. And if you allow the user to enter more grades after showing them, gradeArray[3-4] of the initial grades can be overwritten

Comment: Ok, thank you, I see what you are saying.  The reason of keeping them separate for manipulation purposes makes sense.  I will try to keep that in mind going forward.  I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a while loop to verify the user input. With a while you'll be able to force the user to enter the right grade.

```
if(choice == 'A' || choice == 'a'){
    printf("Enter grade:");
    scanf("%d", &grades);
    getchar();
    while(grade < 1 || grade > 100){
        printf("You entered a wrong number\n");
        printf("Enter a grade between 1 and 100: ");
        scanf("%d", &grades);
        getchar();
    }
    gradeArray[gCount] = grades;
}
```

Comment: I knew it was something like this that I had to be missing and I had tried it numerous ways.  Thank you as I have spent quite a lot of time trying to get that part of this code to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `do-while` loop to keep the program looping back to get another choice unless a valid choice has been entered. Use `fgetc` to read a single character - fewer problems. Only print grades if at least one grade has been entered.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char choice;
    int gradeArray[100];
    int grades;
    int gCount=0,i;
    for(gCount=0; gCount<100; gCount++)
    {
        //for loop to read the grades till array size
        printf("******Enter Choice Selection******\n Add grades(a)\n Quit(q) \n");

        do
          {
          choice = fgetc(stdin);

          if(choice == 'a' || choice == 'A')
            {
            //if user choice is a, then read the grade
            printf( "Enter grade: ");
            scanf("%d", &grades);
            getchar();
            gradeArray[gCount] = grades; //add the grade to array
            }
          else if(choice != 'q')
            printf("Invalid choice - try again\n");
          } while (choice != 'a' && choice != 'A' && choice != 'q');

        if(choice == 'q') //if the user choice is q, then exit the loop
          break;
    }
    
    if(gCount > 0)
      {
      printf("Grades are:\n");
      for(i=0; i<gCount; i++)
          printf(" %d%%\n", gradeArray[i]); //print grades
      }

    return 0;
}
```